# Why ranged based for loop not taking parameter array directly in C++?

Tags: c++

I tried to iterate through the following arr array . but Visual studio shows it has a error.

```
void printArray(int* arr)
{
    for (int i : arr)
    {
        cout << i << ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: Say you pass a random pointer to that. When do you expect the for loop to stop? That's not an array. If it ever was, it's been decayed to a pointer.

Comment: Voted to close because you didn't copy (or even read) the error message. How should the code know the dimensions of arr?

Comment: `arr` isnt an array but just a pointer to an `int`, what should be the end of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `arr` is not an array, it is a pointer. Therefore, it is impossible to determine the number of items in your array from the pointer alone: this is the reason why APIs that take a pointer to array's initial element also take the number of elements in that array, for example:

```
void printArray(int *arr, size_t count)
```

Since the number of items in the array is unknown, `arr` cannot be used in a range loop.

You copy range data into `std::vector` to use it in a range loop:

```
void printArray(int *arr, size_t count) {
    for (int i : vector<int>(arr, arr+count)) {
        cout << i << ",";
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/gHdFlx)

However, passing `std::vector` in place of a pointer is a much better way of achieving the same effect with idiomatic C++ code.

Comment: Maybe add an example how `template <class T, size_t N>` could be helpful here?

Comment: @kay afaik it wont help here, because it doesnt work for dynamically allocated arrays. Anyhow, once you have only a pointer to the first element there is no way to get the size from that pointer alone

Comment: @tobi303 e.g. https://ideone.com/qfL34G

Comment: @kay and? I know that nice trick, but it doenst work for dynamically allocated arrays

Comment: `void Myalgo::printArray(int arr[])
{
 for (int i : arr)
 {
  cout << i << ",";
 }
}`  I tried this way also not working . Instead of pointer i used array. But it is still shows error inside the for each loop

Comment: @Nuwan722 `int arr[]` syntax is identical to `int *arr`. You need a template to capture array size. See ideone link posted by kay above.